# Is there a technical term to describe why we feel the need to put emoticons and smileys in our writing?

Tags: single-word-requests

One often wants to convey a kind of mood when writing a comment to another person, especially if what we're saying is ambiguous or can be taken offensively.  So, one adds a smiley or an emoticon.  Is there a technical term for what they add or impart to the English language?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, if you want a technical term, it's the *limited bandwidth* of text.  (For certain values of "technical"...)  It's frequently claimed that in-person vocal communication is something like 60% body language and 30% tone of voice; in text communication we get neither, implying that we're making do with 10% of the normal bandwidth, or range of expression.  This makes many things that would be clear in in-person vocal communication ambiguous in text, so we invent things like emoticons to try to compensate.

I also occasionally refer to the *emotive flatness* of text.

Comment: Nice. I would add that unadorned text is a *"narrow channel"*.

Answer (score 5):

There may well be a better term for it, but at first blush I would say this is adding *non-verbal cues* to our written interactions.